# Replacing Crystal Report data source with store procedure

Tags: crystal-reports

I used to create crystal reports by going into database expert, selecting tables and specifying the link manually. As I get a bit more comfortable with CR, there is a need for me to put the underlying SQL query into a store procedure to provide data to the report. But doing so will require me to rewrite the whole report which is time consuming.

So, my question is if there are any guru in the community that could and/or have tried to replace the underlying SQL (created by manually add table and links) with a store procedure or cmd without having to rewrite the whole report? I would love to get some hint of how to do that as I have a couple dozen of reports that need "adjustments" and time does not permit me to rewrite them all.

My Crystal Report versions are CR 2008 and CR 2012.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't use a stored procedure with Crystal Reports--use a Command instead.

Comment: Yes... but when I replace the underlying SQL with cmd, all the fields in the report are gone since they are referring to the tables and not cmd. Is it possible to use the exact SQL in cmd and keep the fields in the report?

Answer (score 0):

In case you can use an existing software : this feature is available in a free Crystal reports viewer. Here is the documentation, which explains the use :
http://www.r-tag.com/Documents/RTag%20DataSource.pdf
 ... and here is where you can get your free license:
http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/FreeCrystalReportsViewer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Crystal does an absolutely horrible job of migrating from many tables to a single DB object, be it a Command or stored procedure.

You might be able to `Database | Set datasource location...` to map your SP to one of the many tables in the report (choose the one that has the most fields in use); I've never been able to get this feature to work trying to map a Command to a table.

'Best practice' for a really-poor 'feature' set:

- create a formula field for each field that will be on the canvas, but isn't grouped (these fields won't be removed when you change datasources)
- add the Command to the report; link tables if desired
- manually switch grouping, record-selection formula, sorting, etc.

Comment: Thank you, Craig for your hint/advice/best practice. I found it out the hard way since I was not too well versed in CR then and now live to regret my act every minute of it.